# Terraform error - failed to create kubernetes rest client for read of resource: yaml: line 23: mapping values are not allowed in this context kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks, kubectl

Running into an issue while running terraform scripts ('terraform init' works, then terraform apply or terraform destory gives the following error):

```
│ Error: failed to create kubernetes rest client for read of resource: yaml: line 23: mapping values are not allowed in this context
│
│   with kubectl_manifest.service-account,
│   on roles.tf line 68, in resource "kubectl_manifest" "service-account":
│   68: resource "kubectl_manifest" "service-account" {
```

The following is the kubectl_manifest the error is referring to:

```
resource "kubectl_manifest" "service-account" {
  yaml_body = <<YAML
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: ServiceAccount
  metadata:
    labels:
      app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
      app.kubernetes.io/name: aws-load-balancer-controller
    name: aws-load-balancer-controller
    namespace: kube-system
    annotations:
      eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:role/AmazonEKSLoadBalancerControllerRole_XXXX
YAML
}
```

This same set of terraform scripts has ran successfully and deployed to an AWS EKS cluster in the past, but now when I run them I get the above error.

I've ran the yaml within the kubectl_manifest through YAML validator and made sure there's no misplaced line-endings so I don't think this is to do with the syntax of the YAML itself.

also another strange thing I've noticed is that the error refers to yaml: line 23 but my the yaml_body is not that long so it must be referring to some other yaml file.

I'm expecting these scripts to run without problems but I always get the same error complaining about a yaml line 23 which does not even exist in the kubectl_manifest that the error mentions.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not an official provider. Try doing the same with `kubernetes_manifest` resource.

Comment: @MarkoE Thanks a lot! after making a couple adjustments, `kubernetes_manifest` works and the error is gone.